# Changing classes with jQuery does not work until it is scrolled

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a simple change of classes with jQuery that is activated by scrolling, the .navbar starts with a transparent background and when it moves down it turns yellow. It works as it should, the problem is that it always starts with a yellow background. The temporary solution is to move a little down, then go back up and that's it, but I think it's a very stubborn solution.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
      navbar = $('.navbar');

    if (scrollPos > 50) {
      navbar.addClass('alt-color');
    } else {
      navbar.removeClass('alt-color');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.navbar.alt-color {
  background-color: yellow !important;
} 



.demo {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--Botstrap 3 CSS-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  </head>


    
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top alt-color">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
      
      
<!-- ignore-->
    <section>
      <div class="demo">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue velit, vehicula eu pretium in, semper sit amet sem. Suspendisse tortor quam, tincidunt id nisi ut, hendrerit sodales lectus. Proin quis mauris id arcu molestie euismod.
          Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>



    <!--jQuery-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Botstrap 3 JS-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `alt-color` class from your nav element

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
      navbar = $('.navbar');

    if (scrollPos > 50) {
      navbar.addClass('alt-color');
    } else {
      navbar.removeClass('alt-color');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.navbar.alt-color {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}

.demo {
  width: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--Botstrap 3 CSS-->
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>



<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<!-- ignore-->
<section>
  <div class="demo">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse augue velit, vehicula eu pretium in, semper sit amet sem. Suspendisse tortor quam, tincidunt id nisi ut, hendrerit sodales lectus. Proin quis mauris id arcu molestie euismod. Pellentesque
      habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>



<!--jQuery-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Botstrap 3 JS-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```